# How to get keypress in c# winforms with nothing special selected

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a controller that you can move around by mouseclick.

i want the controller to move by keypress (arrow-keys), too.

what i have is:

```
    private void project1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            MoveUp();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            MoveDown();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
    }

    private void project1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Right:
                e.IsInputKey = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

the MoveDirection() - Methods work fine, cause they are the same when i press the mousebutton.

But i can't get it to work with Arrow-Keys - or any keys ( i also tried WASD for fun, but its not working  - nothing happens! )

What am i doing wrong?

I'm sorry if its a noobish question, i'm still learning c# :)

Comment: is this the parent form, or the control actually getting the events?  check this out - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are going to process repeated key presses (the Cursor keys are kept pressed down), you should ditch the `KeyDown` event and keep the `PreviewKeyDown` handler, which can *handle* a fast/repeated key press quite nicely. In your switch block, set something like this  `case Keys.Down: MoveDown(); break; (...)` etc.

Comment: Keyboard events are raised on the control that has the focus.  Pretty unlikely to be the form in a [winforms] app.  Override ProcessCmdKey() instead.  Or make that control itself aware of such keystrokes, override its IsInputKey() method (same thing as PreviewKeyDown) so it can see them and do what it needs to do.  But that only works as intended when that control always has the focus.  You'll surely favor ProcessCmdKey() for WASD style control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use ProcessCmdKey overridden method for capturing arrows

This ProcessCmdKey is called during message preprocessing to handle command keys, also it is called only when the control is hosted in a Windows Forms application

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    //capture up arrow key
    if (keyData == Keys.Up )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Up arrow key");
        return true;
    }
    //capture down arrow key
    if (keyData == Keys.Down )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Down arrow key");
        return true;
    }
    //capture left arrow key
    if (keyData == Keys.Left)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Left arrow key");
        return true;
    }
    //capture right arrow key
    if (keyData == Keys.Right )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Right arrow key");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

you need to set the Form KeyPreview property to true.

it is recommended to use the KeyPreview property to create a keyboard-handling procedure for a form. For example, when an application uses function keys, setting the KeyPreview property to True allows you to process keystrokes at the form level rather than writing code for each control that might receive keystroke events.